# next() and siblings() can't find button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to change every button element background color in the same row. I've tried using jQuery `siblings()` and `next()` function but it returned **the same** (instead of a button, it returned another element with the accordion-nested-header class):

[image]

My desired result would be like this:

[image]

And this would happen if a user hovers either "gyvulių", "fermų" or "fabrikų". It should change the background color on that row to all buttons.

```js
$('.accordion-nested-header').next().hover(function() {
  $(this).next('button').css('background', 'red');
}, function() {
  $(this).next('button').css('background', '');
});
```

```css
div.accordion-header {
  border: 1px solid #1e5d86;
  background: #f7ba01;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.accordion,
.accordion-nested,
.accordion-nested-parent {
  border: 1px solid #1e5d86;
  border-top: none;
  background: #21aedb;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.accordion.active,
.accordion-nested.active,
.accordion-nested:hover,
.accordion-nested-parent.active,
.accordion-nested-parent:hover,
.accordion:hover {
  background: #0E82A7;
}

.accordion:after,
.accordion-nested:after,
.accordion-nested-parent:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
}

button.accordion.active,
.accordion-nested.active,
.accordion-nested-parent.active {
  border-bottom: none;
}

button.accordion.active:after,
.accordion-nested.active:after,
.accordion-nested-parent.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #f7ba01;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid #1e5d86;
}

td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #21aedb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="accordion-nested-header" style="border: none;">
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
      <button style="border-right: none;" class="accordion-nested top-border">Gyvulių (5%)</button>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
      <button style="border-right: none;" class="accordion-nested top-border">Fermų (10%)</button>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0; ">
      <button style="border-right: none; " class="accordion-nested top-border ">Fabrikų (10%)</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="accordion-nested-header" style="border: none;">
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
      <button style="border-right: none;" class="accordion-nested top-border">Gyvulių (5%)</button>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
      <button style="border-right: none;" class="accordion-nested top-border">Fermų (10%)</button>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0; ">
      <button style="border-right: none; " class="accordion-nested top-border ">Fabrikų (10%)</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: `$('.accordion-nested-header').next()` makes no sense

Comment: I was trying all ways but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to guradio's answer, why not use css when the only event you use is hover?

```
.accordion-nested-header:hover button { background: red; }
```

Comment: I will accept this answer since it uses the only CSS :) If I would need something more advanced, I would prefer @guradio answer.

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis while I appreciate that, please have some more extensive readings about the html/css/js basics. Asking such a question without even thinking about a css only solutions conveys a massive lack of knowledge :)

Comment: alright then ;) you should be good at css before doing jquery stuff, if i may give you that advice

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.accordion-nested-header').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('button').css('background', 'red');
}, function() {
  $(this).find('button').css('background', '');
});
```

```css
div.accordion-header {
  border: 1px solid #1e5d86;
  background: #f7ba01;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.accordion,
.accordion-nested,
.accordion-nested-parent {
  border: 1px solid #1e5d86;
  border-top: none;
  background: #21aedb;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.accordion.active,
.accordion-nested.active,
.accordion-nested:hover,
.accordion-nested-parent.active,
.accordion-nested-parent:hover,
.accordion:hover {
  background: #0E82A7;
}

.accordion:after,
.accordion-nested:after,
.accordion-nested-parent:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
}

button.accordion.active,
.accordion-nested.active,
.accordion-nested-parent.active {
  border-bottom: none;
}

button.accordion.active:after,
.accordion-nested.active:after,
.accordion-nested-parent.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #f7ba01;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid #1e5d86;
}

td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #21aedb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="accordion-nested-header" style="border: none;">
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
      <button style="border-right: none;" class="accordion-nested top-border">Gyvulių (5%)</button>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
      <button style="border-right: none;" class="accordion-nested top-border">Fermų (10%)</button>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0; ">
      <button style="border-right: none; " class="accordion-nested top-border ">Fabrikų (10%)</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="accordion-nested-header" style="border: none;">
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
      <button style="border-right: none;" class="accordion-nested top-border">Gyvulių (5%)</button>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
      <button style="border-right: none;" class="accordion-nested top-border">Fermų (10%)</button>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0; ">
      <button style="border-right: none; " class="accordion-nested top-border ">Fabrikų (10%)</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

1. remove next since you want to change the child element.
2. use find to get the button in the hovered tr

Comment: Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis glad to help mate :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `find()` function because the button is inside the accordion

```js
$('.accordion-nested-header').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('button').css('background', 'red');
}, function() {
  $(this).find('button').css('background', '');
});
```

```css
div.accordion-header {
  border: 1px solid #1e5d86;
  background: #f7ba01;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.accordion,
.accordion-nested,
.accordion-nested-parent {
  border: 1px solid #1e5d86;
  border-top: none;
  background: #21aedb;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.accordion.active,
.accordion-nested.active,
.accordion-nested:hover,
.accordion-nested-parent.active,
.accordion-nested-parent:hover,
.accordion:hover {
  background: #0E82A7;
}

.accordion:after,
.accordion-nested:after,
.accordion-nested-parent:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
}

button.accordion.active,
.accordion-nested.active,
.accordion-nested-parent.active {
  border-bottom: none;
}

button.accordion.active:after,
.accordion-nested.active:after,
.accordion-nested-parent.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #f7ba01;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid #1e5d86;
}

td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #21aedb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="accordion-nested-header" style="border: none;">
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
      <button style="border-right: none;" class="accordion-nested top-border">Gyvulių (5%)</button>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
      <button style="border-right: none;" class="accordion-nested top-border">Fermų (10%)</button>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0; ">
      <button style="border-right: none; " class="accordion-nested top-border ">Fabrikų (10%)</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="accordion-nested-header" style="border: none;">
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
      <button style="border-right: none;" class="accordion-nested top-border">Gyvulių (5%)</button>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
      <button style="border-right: none;" class="accordion-nested top-border">Fermų (10%)</button>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0; ">
      <button style="border-right: none; " class="accordion-nested top-border ">Fabrikų (10%)</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Everything is fine, except first row doesn't work the same as the second one :) But, anyway, thank you for your efforts  :) +1

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis i thought you just wanted the second row to behave that way.. just remove the `.next() ` from the `$('.accordion-nested-header').next().hover(function() ` :)

Answer (score 1):

Add css part

```
.accordion-nested-header:hover td button {
  background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use JS/Jquery to do this.. simple CSS is enough....

```
.accordion-nested-header:hover button{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
     $('button').hover(function() {
       var el = $(this);
       var currentRow = el.parents('.accordion-nested-header');
       currentRow.find('button').addClass('blue');
     });
     $('button').mouseout(function() {
      var el = $(this);
      var currentRow = el.parents('.accordion-nested-header');
      currentRow.find('button').removeClass('blue');
     });
 });
</script>
```

Now the css part

```
<style type="text/css">
  .blue {
    background: blue;
  }
</style>
```